# PHP include a text file whilst keeping carriage returns?

Tags: php, file-handling, carriage-return, php-include

I have a text file that I'm including on my page, however the carriage returns aren't there as they are in the text document. How can I keep them as they are in the text document?

Comment: Please explain better what you need and show some code

Comment: php include("include/content.txt")

Comment: Why do you want the carriage returns?

Comment: Have you tried `nl2br`?

Comment: What kind of content is it in content.txt ?

Comment: Just text, no tags. The input generated by user into the file has been sanitized if that's what you're thinking.

Answer (score 1):

```
$textfile = fopen('file.txt','r');
$readfile = fread($textfile); 
echo nl2br($readfile);
```

Comment: Sadly this only returns the first paragraph where the first carriage return occurs

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks have no meaning in normal HTML (other than just being whitespace). You either need to convert them to HTML line breaks using `nl2br()`, or put the content of the text file in a `<pre></pre>` block.